# HTMLUnit cannot find element

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

Using HTMLUnit I am trying to click a button on a certain site after logging in with Java

The login appears to be successful however, when I attempt to click a button (which uses a JS script and is defined by id="buttonGetDetails"), it throws an error that it cannot find an element by that id

"true" is a bool that I set and "login successful" is a `System.out.println` to use during testing

```
Error:
elementName=[*] attributeName=[id] attributeValue=[buttonGetDetails]
true
Login successful
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getHtmlElementById(HtmlPage.java:1597)
```

Comment: Use `htmlPage.asXml()` to see what HtmlUnit sees, and check if there are any JavaScript errors logged.  Also, try to provide minimal reproducible case.

Answer (score 0):

The page might take some time to load after you login and your code to find the button executes before the page is loaded. Try using explicit wait. http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/

Comment: It is not recommended to use Thread.sleep as it might halt process of loading the page. Adding explicit wait is just 2 lines of code:
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));`